# How to move a wordpress installation from xampp localhost to linux server?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, unix

I created a Wordpress site offline and after finishing it I want to move it to a server. Moving the wordpress directory with all the files was easy. And I also exported my wp database with localhost/phpmyadmin to an sql-file. There are some servers which support phpmyadmin which would make the database import on the server easy. But how to do it with unix commands?

According to [this site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-import-command/) I have to create a database on the server first and then import the sql file.

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e 'create database salesdb1;'
$ mysql -u salesdb1 -p sales < sales.sql
```

I figured out that "-p" stands for password and I didn't need it because there was no password. Before I do anything wrong I have a question - where to put my sql file on the server and how to import it?

```
$ mysql -u <my_unix_user> ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the sql sump file in your `/tmp` directory  or any other folder where your user has full rights on it.
**From unix comd line :**
-alter the cmd and input your own values.

```
 unix cmd line:> mysql -u root -p <passwrd> -e 'create database db_name; use db_name; source /tmp/dump_file.sql; grant all on db_name.* to user_name@'% - or an ip address' identified by 'password';  flush privileges;
```

**From inside the database:**

```
unix cmd line:> mysql -u root -p <passwrd>
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 58208
Server version: 5.6.10 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

create database db_name;
use db_name;
source /tmp/dump_file.sql --full path to the dump file
grant all on db_name.* to user_name@'% - or an ip address' identified by 'password';
flush privileges;
```

- make sure the db users has privileges to `create database`.
- the `user_name@'% - or an ip address'` Here you need to state the ip address of the app server, if it's on the same machine as the database use `localhost` if you want it to connect from any place use the wildcard `%'

---

**To add an user with no password follow here:**
(i don't recommend this - but to answer your question)

```
unix cmd line:>mysql -uroot -p passwd -e 'grant all on *.* to test123@'%' identified by ''; flush privileges;
```

**Next connect to the db :**

```
[root@fgv180b ~]# mysql -utest123  
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 60722
Server version: 5.6.10 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

**To test you db connection :**
-create and call a php with this content !

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: thx. But how to get "inside the database"? Or how to write multiple lines with $ mysql -u root -p -e '<database command line>'? I'm not good at unix commands, sorry :(

Comment: Ok thanks! I did import the sql file. But there is still following error in the browser: "Error establishing a database connection". Well I didn't type the last two lines because my root should already have all permissions and there is no password so I didn't know what to write instead of "identified by...". WP-config seems to be right too. I'll check out what it could be. But thank you very much you solved the import problem!

Comment: i suggest to setup a password ! else just use this "identified by ''" - see my updated answer

Comment: I tried "grant all on *.* to root@'%' identified by ''; flush privileges;" and then used a php-script from this site:http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/ and following error occured: "Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" - so something is wrong with the login because the script was simply: mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

Comment: use insted - mysql -uroot -p passwd -e 'grant all on *.* to test123@'localhost' identified by ''; flush privileges;

Comment: Thx again but there were some typos ;) I tried: "mysql -u root -e 'grant all on . to root@'localhost' identified by ''; flush privileges;'" and some other lines but everytime there was the ">"-symbol. What has to be masked in that command line and what not?

Comment: I tried "SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'localhost';" and console returned: "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*F45...' WITH GRANT OPTION" - so it's already set up I guess...

Comment: just add a new param in the mysql_connect() - containing your password !

Comment: Dammit! The owner of that server told me there is no password and I thought the pass string is just an encrypted empty string or something. Now I showed the errors to him and now I have the pass. The php connection script worked now but wordpress not. Probably I destroyed the table by trying to get it fixed. I will try my luck tomorrow again. At the moment I'm to frustrated for it. Thank you soo much for your help!!!

Answer (score -1):

please have a look at the following from wordpress website

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress
```